# Invantive Data Hub: What is the difference between a standard installation and a "static deployment"

Tags: deployment, clickonce

Invantive Data Hub has two options to install the software. What is the difference between a `standard installation` and a `"static deployment"` for Invantive Data Hub?

And why should I choose one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

### **Standard Installation**

The standard installation uses ClickOnce from Microsoft. This means that the software will get upgraded if needed when the application starts. But this also means that the folder containing the software wil differ per version.

---

### **Static Deployment**

With a static deployment the installation folder doesn't change, but upgrades should be performed manually. This can be done for example by executing the statement `local deploy static` within Data Hub. For Data Hub we recommend the use of a static deployment so you can use a hardcoded location path in batch scripts.